# How do I get the position of a CALayer subLayer that is arranged via constraints?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, calayer

How can I get the current position of a `CALayer` instance in the coordinates of its super layer? (Mac application)

I would have expected this to be available from the `frame` property but it isn't. In particular, this `CALayer`instance has been positioned using various `CAConstraint` types and I have not specified the `(x,y) position` explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have gone away when I check the frame "later" during the execution of the program.

In the question I was checking the bounds during the `init` and I can thus assume that the actual layout had not taken place yet and hence the runtime didn't know what the position actually was - it was indeterminate at that point.